# Configuring PHP 5.5.x as an Apache 1.3 module

Tags: php, apache

OK, let me start by saying there are lengthy reasons why I am forced to use Apache 1.3 in this particular case.  So any answer that says "You need to upgrade to Apache 2.x", or "It works under Apache 2.x" will not be of use.  :)

Apache 1.3 is compiled with mod_so, it shows up in the list when I do an *httpd -l*.

PHP is configured with *--with-apxs=/usr/sbin/apxs*, and that is the correct location for the Apache 1.3's apxs.

The httpd.conf file includes:

```
LoadModule php5_module        /usr/libexec/apache/libphp5.so
AddModule mod_php5.c
```

and */usr/libexec/apache* is the correct location for the *libphp5.so* file.

When I start Apache, I get:

```
Starting httpd: Syntax error on line 79 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:
Can't locate API module structure `php5_module' in file /usr/libexec/apache/libphp5.so: /usr/libexec/apache/libphp5.so: undefined symbol: php5_module
```

*ldd /usr/libexec/apache/libphp5.so* shows:

```
linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0x00d78000)
libcrypt.so.1 => /lib/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00d40000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/libz.so.1 (0x0018c000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/librt.so.1 (0x001a0000)
libcurl.so.4 => /usr/lib/libcurl.so.4 (0x001a9000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0x00466000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0x00212000)
libnsl.so.1 => /lib/libnsl.so.1 (0x00217000)
libxml2.so.2 => /usr/lib/libxml2.so.2 (0x00311000)
libssl.so.10 => /usr/lib/libssl.so.10 (0x00232000)
libcrypto.so.10 => /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.10 (0x00d79000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x00f06000)
libfreebl3.so => /lib/libfreebl3.so (0x0028b000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00c98000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x002f1000)
libcares.so.2 => /usr/lib/libcares.so.2 (0x002e0000)
libidn.so.11 => /lib/libidn.so.11 (0x00cb3000)
libldap-2.4.so.2 => /lib/libldap-2.4.so.2 (0x00ce5000)
libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /lib/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x03f35000)
libkrb5.so.3 => /lib/libkrb5.so.3 (0x03bd4000)
libk5crypto.so.3 => /lib/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x02a7f000)
libcom_err.so.2 => /lib/libcom_err.so.2 (0x0045c000)
libssh2.so.1 => /usr/lib/libssh2.so.1 (0x056eb000)
libresolv.so.2 => /lib/libresolv.so.2 (0x010a1000)
liblber-2.4.so.2 => /lib/liblber-2.4.so.2 (0x076d0000)
libssl3.so => /usr/lib/libssl3.so (0x078f7000)
libsmime3.so => /usr/lib/libsmime3.so (0x0537d000)
libnss3.so => /usr/lib/libnss3.so (0x03117000)
libnssutil3.so => /usr/lib/libnssutil3.so (0x063ae000)
libplds4.so => /lib/libplds4.so (0x00d71000)
libplc4.so => /lib/libplc4.so (0x00490000)
libnspr4.so => /lib/libnspr4.so (0x01e85000)
libsasl2.so.2 => /usr/lib/libsasl2.so.2 (0x054bc000)
libkrb5support.so.0 => /lib/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x00d33000)
libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x00461000)
libselinux.so.1 => /lib/libselinux.so.1 (0x030bb000)
```

Note that there is a *ClearModuleList* in the https.conf, but the right modules are added back after it, and I get the same results when *ClearModuleList* is commented out.

I am leaning towards an issue with PHP compilation since the required module does, in fact, seem to be missing, but there were no errors when configuring and compiling PHP.

Any ideas?